# Unable to change the active target framework in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

My C# class library targets several versions of .NET.

```
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0;net6.0;net5.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

But as I edit the code, it seems to show .NET Standard as the active target by graying out lines that are for non-.NET Standard targets.

[image]

My question is: Where is this set? How does it determine which target is the active target. I've looked everywhere but can't see how to change this.

Comment: What's in the project properties? As far as I'm aware, you can only select one target there. That would be the target you would build against if you selected Build in the IDE.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: The `<TargetFrameworks>` tag was from the project properties. It's a  NuGet package, so I have several targets. But I only want to set one current target. But I don't see where I can do that.

Comment: There is a graphic explanation of this in the documentation of vs for mac, which is also applicable. you can view [Working with code in a multi-target project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/project-multitargeting?view=vsmac-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2022#working-with-code-in-a-multi-target-project).

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT: Thanks. The thing that was confusing is that it seemed like this recently changed. It used to be in one of the toolbar dropdowns. Now that I know where it is, it actually makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the drop down at the top of the document to change your target framework.

[image]